# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined while accessing "photo_reference" property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Below is the JSON i get from the google places API. Parsing the Json with JSON.parse(body). The "results" key is an array of Objects that i am looping through to access the property of photos. Hope the code is clearer now. I have pasted in the valid JSON that i am getting from the api call.

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CqQCGwEAAI5PpCTJI6Qoa1CD9iA4EpJha6t0gMlZ3I3DpOIVgE1BUYh5NNI0lXRuvAltI8RhOilTNJggXsR3TEP2C6hoIsibEWZXnZClbEcZzes7LGqJuQ0heJWipe7RNbxq8S8zuao1HWfECs11i44WO0Luv-4bYx5GlCEj6Wl07LitkzwG4u0e4FyIHogyaShky5Awd44ZyOcqKzy7wYBr7p37j6A6PMdR7zn7cMWQKiVolfHQbFZerVJ3JJ5MiKSshocG189wPKjqJzSACE6W19LmZ7TIMB9qm7jQANNQStrsq7rYAWIBQ-UqJ_6Hv9jv1xL7eRQ9bkyR17u7xPZWfeCU69u_PQmGvuvSWNJDvNUuoI-uwLc_RhgTZp26kyzMlXwYHRIQXy13ridwzgvlBU8ez_y-WBoUcBN7UvN8Q8iuDyS_LjXEWmT_sIk",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 28.615572,
               "lng" : 77.3468
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 28.6169209802915,
                  "lng" : 77.34814898029151
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 28.6142230197085,
                  "lng" : 77.34545101970849
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "dea8496f678dc1f01381a85298e37a0905a3ca11",
         "name" : "Malabar Junction Restaurant",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 746,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117230637789134827076/photos\"\u003eSwati\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAArbpjr1fjNp2Fc4ww8Vkgrzzzt5aHEvACzEZFa-XCJU3Fw2JqFLSDo64jlFWwDZwdYaFP_cIgdqI37TJ25mVB2W_rtoTv_aI0LJGgnh_P4-UF7u45ZvqdM-bE4ljYD2yyEhDjv-4AWC5AKcE713GL1qAsGhQjAN2oS1KWv52f8XsjEK3Pmnv53w",
               "width" : 750
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJx6qqqj3lDDkRcBw22oTfWgk",
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAAZBpNfAiO2G_y57bLoFTSM28MG4xUi-VAg3kJgV2ZzksdhpzySwxdPNdPP1paEIE46i70oxgLHliUcEjxalukNEyhN85J-ryRbXVVMkg4Tz-MGBGhgVur7SV5b4IFePnfEhABXu9pHswL4Up5w-k9td94GhSDs13DRQVxPOpI8iWqUbLyd_WJUg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "62, 8, Rani Jhansi Marg, Block 10, Sector 10, Noida"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Trying to Access the photo_reference property like so

```
let resultJSON = JSON.parse(body);
let results = resultJSON["results"];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
   let name = results[i]["name"];
   console.log(results[i].photos[0].photo_reference);
}
```

Comment: try `console.log(results[i]["photos"][0].photo_reference)`. The reason is that photo_reference is a field (not an array index or map key) and `results[i]["photos"][0]` is an object which is why you need the `.` operator

Comment: Thank you for Replying.
Tried but it crashes with the same error. TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
It is crashing while trying to access the first element of photos

Comment: This is plainly not the actual JSON.  For one thing it doesn't parse as is.  Furthermore, there is no `results`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty is right, you really should update the question to include valid JSON.

Comment: results is an array of objects. I am simply looping through it.
console.log(results[i].photos[0].photo_reference) also crashes with the same error

Comment: @shivamkaushik Your code works, the error must be somewhere else; with the test data provided(and scrubbed for privacy), https://jsfiddle.net/mo2baawp/ I was unable to reproduce the bug you spoke of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that shows your updated code is working.

```js
let resultJSON = {
  "html_attributions": [],
  "next_page_token": "CqQCGwEAAI5PpCTJI6Qoa1CD9iA4EpJha6t0gMlZ3I3DpOIVgE1BUYh5NNI0lXRuvAltI8RhOilTNJggXsR3TEP2C6hoIsibEWZXnZClbEcZzes7LGqJuQ0heJWipe7RNbxq8S8zuao1HWfECs11i44WO0Luv-4bYx5GlCEj6Wl07LitkzwG4u0e4FyIHogyaShky5Awd44ZyOcqKzy7wYBr7p37j6A6PMdR7zn7cMWQKiVolfHQbFZerVJ3JJ5MiKSshocG189wPKjqJzSACE6W19LmZ7TIMB9qm7jQANNQStrsq7rYAWIBQ-UqJ_6Hv9jv1xL7eRQ9bkyR17u7xPZWfeCU69u_PQmGvuvSWNJDvNUuoI-uwLc_RhgTZp26kyzMlXwYHRIQXy13ridwzgvlBU8ez_y-WBoUcBN7UvN8Q8iuDyS_LjXEWmT_sIk",
  "results": [{
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 28.615572,
        "lng": 77.3468
      },
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 28.6169209802915,
          "lng": 77.34814898029151
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 28.6142230197085,
          "lng": 77.34545101970849
        }
      }
    },
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    "id": "dea8496f678dc1f01381a85298e37a0905a3ca11",
    "name": "Malabar Junction Restaurant",
    "opening_hours": {
      "open_now": true,
      "weekday_text": []
    },
    "photos": [{
      "height": 746,
      "html_attributions": [
        "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117230637789134827076/photos\"\u003eSwati\u003c/a\u003e"
      ],
      "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAArbpjr1fjNp2Fc4ww8Vkgrzzzt5aHEvACzEZFa-XCJU3Fw2JqFLSDo64jlFWwDZwdYaFP_cIgdqI37TJ25mVB2W_rtoTv_aI0LJGgnh_P4-UF7u45ZvqdM-bE4ljYD2yyEhDjv-4AWC5AKcE713GL1qAsGhQjAN2oS1KWv52f8XsjEK3Pmnv53w",
      "width": 750
    }],
    "place_id": "ChIJx6qqqj3lDDkRcBw22oTfWgk",
    "reference": "CmRRAAAAZBpNfAiO2G_y57bLoFTSM28MG4xUi-VAg3kJgV2ZzksdhpzySwxdPNdPP1paEIE46i70oxgLHliUcEjxalukNEyhN85J-ryRbXVVMkg4Tz-MGBGhgVur7SV5b4IFePnfEhABXu9pHswL4Up5w-k9td94GhSDs13DRQVxPOpI8iWqUbLyd_WJUg",
    "scope": "GOOGLE",
    "types": ["restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
    "vicinity": "62, 8, Rani Jhansi Marg, Block 10, Sector 10, Noida"
  }],
  "status": "OK"
}

let results = resultJSON["results"];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  let name = results[i]["name"];
  console.log(results[i].photos[0].photo_reference);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use square brackets to access objects?

Comment: ^ I edited the answer to clarify. You cant use square brackets to access an object's properties.

Comment: @shivamkaushik I did; please provide more information, and see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958970/typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined-while-accessing-photo-referenc/47959057#comment82887985_47958970).

Comment: I stand corrected regarding accessing object properties with square brackets, thank @Daedalus. That part of the answer wasn't correct or helpful so it has been removed.